# Why do Python modules sometimes not import their sub-modules?

Tags: python, python-import

I noticed something weird today I would like explained. I wasn't 100% sure how to even phrase this as a question, so google is out of the question. The logging module does not have access to the module logging.handlers for some odd reason. Try it yourself if you don't believe me:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.handlers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'handlers'
>>> import logging.handlers
>>> logging.handlers
<module 'logging.handlers' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/logging/handlers.pyc'>
```

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

In Python, modules need to be imported before they're accessible. `import logging` imports just the logging module. It so happens that `logging` is a package with submodules, but those submodules are still not automatically loaded. So, you need to explicitly import `logging.handlers` before you can access it.

If you're wondering why it looks like sometimes you don't need those extra imports: some packages import some or all of their submodules when they are imported -- simply by doing those imports in their `__init__.py` files. In other cases it might be that something else that you import, also imported `logging.handlers`. It doesn't matter which piece of code does the import; as long as *something* in your process imports `logging.handlers` before you access it, it'll be there. And sometimes a module that looks like a package really isn't one, like `os` and `os.path`. `os` isn't a package, it just imports the correct other module (for your platform) and calls it `path`, just so you can access it as `os.path`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also new to python and after having lots of practice now I can differentiate between, 
package (folder) , module(.py) , classes,variables...etc...

if you want any of your folder to be python package - It must contain `__init__.py` file even empty file will do !!!

and as Thomas said, you can import extra module in `__init__.p`y if you want !!! but modules/packages are accessible only after importing it...

if you want to import everything from a module you can use

```
from logging import *
```

rest you can access the handlers module like below too,

```
from logging import handlers
print dir(handlers)
```

Comment: Please do not use `from module import *`. It's almost always a mistake.

Comment: If you want everything in a package to be imported automatically, do those imports in __init__.py, instead of setting __all__ in __init__.py and doing 'from package import *' somewhere.

Comment: `from module import *` isn't ALWAYS a mistake, though 99.9% of the time it is at least with built-in modules. There are a couple of modules that I use that require wildcard importing because they define a lot of constants that need to be used.

Comment: Someone please explain why 'from module import *' is problematic

Comment: @Pete: because it "pollutes" the standard namespace which leads to ambiguity and conflict. If I had `import zipper` and `zipper.open()` you'd know exactly which open I was calling. Contrariwise `from zipper import *` followed by `open()` is it the built-in open or zipper.open or something else. `import zipper as z` is much preferred if you get tired of typing `zipper`

Comment: @Pete: It's also a problem because you might overwrite some of your namespace unknowingly. I used to use from `numpy import *` because some numpy functions don't work unless you import all of numpy (terrible design flaw on their part IMO) but numpy has a HUGE number of objects that it imports. I ended up overwriting a lot of functions (I believe copy was one... I'm too tired to check). Now I do import numpy as np if I'm going to use numpy so much that I can't stand to type it over and over.

Comment: @dustynachos, which numpy function have that flaw?

Answer (score 4):

[Thomas Wouters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17624/thomas-wouters) answered this question very well, but alas, I only found this question after finding the answer in the original documentation. To that end I thought I would add to this in the hopes it pops up closer to the top of the search engine in the future.

### **QUESTION**

> Why does the error: '**AttributeError: module '*module_name*' has no attribute '*sub_module_name***' appear even
>   though my editor (e.g. Visual Code) auto-completes the sub-module
>   name:

```
 import module_name
 module_name.sub_module_name(parameter)
```

### **ANSWER**

> Your editor is basing its autocomplete off of the file structure of your project and not off of Python behavior. Sub-modules are not
>   'automatically' imported when you import a module. Reference [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules) for details on how to 'automatically' import sub-modules when using

```
 import module_name
```

The key contribution with this answer being the addition of AttributeError when trying to import a 'module' or 'package'

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

I've faced recently the same odd situation. So, I bet you've removed some third-party lib import. That removed lib contained
`from logging import handlers` or `from logging import *` and provided you `handlers`. And in other script you've had something like `import logging` and just used `logging.handlers` and you've thought that is a way things work as I did.