# AttributeError: 'module' object (scipy) has no attribute 'misc'

Tags: python, scipy

I updated from ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 12.10 and the python module I have written suddenly no longer works with the error message that the module scipy does not have the attribute 'misc'. This worked previously. I am still using python 2.7 after the update. Here is where the code crashes

```
import scipy
scipy.misc.imsave(slice,dat)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I found an equivalent function pylab.imsave which works.

Comment: Related: [Why do Python modules sometimes not import their sub-modules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781522/why-do-python-modules-sometimes-not-import-their-sub-modules)

Comment: Also check that you have **pillow**. Without **pillow** _imsave_ doesn't export. **pip install pillow**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860317/how-u-can-fix-this-problem-attributeerror-scipy-object-scipy-has-no-attribu/61860318#61860318

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.misc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'misc'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import scipy.misc
>>> scipy.misc.imsave
<function imsave at 0x19cfa28>
>>>
```

Which seems to be quite common with `scipy`.

Comment: @SibbsGambling for the why: Why do Python modules sometimes not import their sub-modules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781522/why-do-python-modules-sometimes-not-import-their-sub-modules

Answer (score 9):

Because you cannot directly use the misc module from scipy without explicitly import it. Here is the way of loading scipy.misc:

```
import scipy.misc

#Load the Lena image into an array, (yes scipy does have a lena function)
lena = scipy.misc.lena()
...
```

Comment: Similarly this is true for scipy.linalg 
```import scipy.linalg 
     scipy.linalg.lu(..)
```

Comment: This should be the right answer...

Answer (score 8):

imread is depreciated after version 1.2.0 ! 
So to solve the problem I had to install 1.1.0 version.

```
 pip install scipy==1.1.0
```

Comment: imsave is also deprecated.
It is recommended to use https://imageio.readthedocs.io/ now.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html

Comment: If you are using Python 3.6, this fixes the problem. However, the problem cannot be fixed with recent Python versions (I tried with Python 3.9 with no luck) because that scipy version and `imsave` are deprecated, as @Atnas has pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to explicitly import `scipy.misc` as:

   `import scipy.misc`
2. You need to install the package **pillow** (formerly known as PIL), if not already installed. For image manipulation functions of `scipy.misc` such as `imread()` or `imsave()` to function correctly, pillow has to be installed.
   To verify, either run your code again or type the below command:

   `scipy.misc.imread`

Comment: yeah~, for me ,I didn't install pillow and it's ok after I installed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I was trying to import `comb` from `scipy.misc`, which had been depreciated in `scipy 1.0.0` [(see ref here)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/misc.html). Thus, I was inevitabely getting `AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'comb'`.

Replacing `scipy.misc.comb` with `scipy.special.comb` fixed the issue.