# SciPy least squares solver scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr not working

Tags: python, scipy

I'm having trouble using the least squares solver scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr, I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lsmr'
```

at the top of my script I have

```
import scipy.sparse.linalg
```

I have of coursed tried google, but came up with nothing as the error is quite vague.

Does anybody have an idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object (scipy) has no attribute 'misc'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581593/attributeerror-module-object-scipy-has-no-attribute-misc)

Comment: @duffymo: no, the `import` is correct here.

Answer (score 0):

what version of scipy do you have installed? You should have a lsmr.py in your python libraries. In Slackware 14.1 Mine is located in

```
$ locate lsmr.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/lsmr.py
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/lsmr.pyc
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/tests/test_lsmr.py
```

If the lsmr algorithm is more sutable to your applcation you may be able to upgrade Scipy, with pip, or find a compatible version of the library at. https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/lsmr.py I have also used the anaconda python installer in my home directory with much sucess.

Comment: Well I executed 'locate lsmr.py' and it doesn't return anything..

However, I changed lsmr to lsqr (which seems to do the same), and this one works.

I don't have any problems with other scipy functions, so I find it quite odd. 

Anyway, thanks for the suggestion :)