# Errors about using scipy.stats.uniform

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, ipython

I am using python 3.4 with Spyder 2.3.4

I want to use uniform distribution function from scipy.stats.uniform. I wrote two different codes for importing this function, only one work. I don't know why. I also have the question with the results from the working one. Since my 3 questions are all based on the same code, it is better to ask them all in one post.

The code that does not work (Code 1)

```
import scipy as sp
a = 0
b = 1
mean = (a+b)/2
variance = 1/12*(b-a)**2
std = sp.sqrt(variance)
rv = sp.stats.uniform.rvs(loc = mean, scale = std, size = 10)
a = rv(>=0.5)*1
print(a)
```

when I run the program, it says "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stats'".

The code that works (Code 2)

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy.stats import uniform
# form a unifrom distribution bewteen 0 and 1.
a = 0
b = 1
mean = (a+b)/2
variance = 1/12*(b-a)**2
std = sp.sqrt(variance)
rv = uniform.rvs(loc = mean, scale = std, size = 10)
a = (rv>=0.5)*1
print(a)
```

I am sure there is no syntax error. I just can run this on my computer.

My questions:

1. Since the "stats" is in "scipy", why `sp.stats.uniform` in Code 1 does not work? The difference between Code 1 and Code 2 is: in Code 1, I only `import scipy as sp`, and then tried to call function uniform by `sp.stats.uniform`; while in Code 2, I first `from scipy.stats import uniform`, then just call function uniform by `uniform`.
2. In the Code 2, the following syntax is OK.

   ```
   rv = sp.stats.uniform.rvs(loc = mean, scale = std, size = 6)
   ```

   It seems that if I called `from scipy.stats import uniform` (as in the beginning of Code 2), then I can use `sp.stats.uniform`. Why?
3. As you can see in Code 2, I want to generate 10 random points from uniform distribution between 0 and 1. According to the theory, its mean is 0.5, and standard deviation is sqrt(1/12). What I expect is the generated 10 points will have more or less 5 points less than 0.5 and 5 points larger than 0.5. But the resulting "a" contains only 1, meaning "rv" is always larger than 0.5. Did I use the "uniform" function correctly?

Comment: If you look at the scipy `__init__.py` the answer will be obvious.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581593/attributeerror-module-object-scipy-has-no-attribute-misc/13581936#13581936

Comment: In general, best avoid blank `import scipy`,  import the submodule you actually need.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, thank you for your help. I checked `help(sp.__init__)`, but I don't know how to understand it regarding my questions 1 and 2. Could you please tell me more?

Comment: @ev-br, thank you for your help. The "similar question" you mentioned is not completely answered (in my opinion). For example: when only blank import `import scipy as sp`, `sp.stats` does not work, but `sp.sqrt` works. It seems "stats" and "sqrt" are treated differently in scipy. Am I correct?

Comment: @aura, `import scipy;scipy.__file__` then open the `__init__.py` file using the path returned

Comment: There is a difference between importing a package and a module