# Can anyone explain the difference between these imports of scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

In a laboratory class at Uni, one version of my code failed, while another passed, and I was hoping someone could explain why these are any different?

The version that failed was:

```
import scipy as sc

def trapez(f, a, b, n)
    h = (b - a) / n
    c = list(range(1, n))
    return (h / 2) * (f(a) + f(b) + 2 * sum(f(a + i * h) for i in c))

def finderror(n)
    def f(x):
        return x ** 2
    l = sc.integrate.quad(f, -1, 2)
    return l[0] - trapez(f, -1, 2, n)
```

The version that passed was:

```
import scipy.integrate as sc

def trapez(f, a, b, n):
    h = (b - a) / n
    c = list(range(1, n))
    return (h / 2) * (f(a) + f(b) + 2 * sum(f(a + i * h) for i in c))

def finderror(n):
    def f(x):
        return x ** 2
    l = sc.quad(f, -1, 2)
    return l[0] - trapez(f, -1, 2, n)
```

Both of these returned the exact same answers, hence my confusion at one 'failing'.

Thank you in advance for any advice! (I have already completed this, so this isn't me trying to get answers)

Comment: What do you mean by "failed" or "passed"?

Comment: Post the error you got (with stack trace)

Comment: When I say failed or passed, it's an online email submission, that returns an email passing or failing each function. The Error that the email listed was:
E    AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'integrate'

Comment: @JosephWard. `integrate` is a sub-module, not an attribute.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Submodules of a package are stored as attributes of the package object at runtime.

Comment: Quoting from the [Introduction to the SciPy Tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html#scipy-organization): "Scipy sub-packages need to be imported separately".  Usually the only reason to import just `scipy` is to check the version stored as `scipy.__version__`.  All the subpackages require explicit imports.  (I'd make this an answer, but I'm sure the question is a duplicate, even though I didn't find an obvious candidate for the dupe in a brief search.)

Comment: @user2357112. Nope. For example, the `encodings` package in the standard library contains dozens of sub-modules - but `import encodings` does not automatically import them all, so they are not available as attributes. Of course, sub-modules can be explicitly imported in the `__init__.py` of a package - which is why the *aliases.py* sub-module **is** automatically available as `encodings.aliases`.

Comment: @ekhumoro: Let me rephrase that. *Once loaded*, submodules of a package are stored as attributes of the package object.

Comment: @user2357112. There doesn't seem to be a term to distinguish between attributes/variables that are defined by the module itself (roughly equivalent to `__all__`), and those that just end up in its namespace by other means. Anyway, that's what I was getting at in my original comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object (scipy) has no attribute 'misc'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581593/attributeerror-module-object-scipy-has-no-attribute-misc)

Answer (score 2):

If you just `import scipy as sc`, that doesn't load the `scipy.integrate` submodule. You need to `import scipy.integrate` explicitly.

If the first snippet seemed to work when you tried it, that's because you didn't test it in isolation. You tried it in an environment where `scipy.integrate` had already been loaded by other imports.

Comment: This was suggested by someone on my course. I tried it later and it did work when I just imported scipy as sc, then used     sc.integrate.quad(function and arguments