# Using signal processing library in scipy

Tags: python, scipy

I want to use the signal processing library under Scipy. But running the following example code given in Scipy webpage has given me an error. I have rechecked my Scipy installation and it is the latest.

The example code I ran is as follows

```
from scipy import signal 
import numpy as nu
b=nu.array([0.5,0.25])
a=nu.array([1.0,-1.0/3])
C=nu.array([[0,1]])
D=nu.array([[0]])
num=[1,3,3]
den=[1,2,1]
sys=signal.TransferFunction(num,den)
print sys
```

When I ran it, it gives:

```
$ python trial.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys=signal.TransferFunction(num,den)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TransferFunction'
```

Comment: `TransferFunction` was added to `scipy.signal` in [version 0.16.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/release.0.16.0.html).  You can check which version you have with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TransferFunction'
```

This is the key phrase you want to search based on. Have you tried importing the module explicitly?

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581593/attributeerror-module-object-scipy-has-no-attribute-misc) could give you more information related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **scipy** version you have installed, if you have an older version of **scipy** the `TransferFunction` might not be there, due to which you are seeing the `AttributeError`

For me your code worked fine for **latest version of scipy**