# Having a problem in scipy.stats fro importing describe()

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, scipy, statistics

In Scipy documentation, it clearly says for using statistics(especially for a short description of an array):

```
Import scipy
scipy.stats.describe(a, axis=0, ddof=1, bias=True, nan_policy='propagate')
```

But I get the AttributeError: 
module 'scipy' has no attribute 'stats'

then in another part of the documentation, it says :

`from scipy import stats`

which works fine for me. Actually, I don't get the exact difference between . and from ...... import ...... and why the first one doesn't work.
Thank you so much for your help. I would appreciate it if you guys can provide me some links too.

Comment: I'll just add that I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but both statements work for me. Maybe post your version of scipy?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the version of scipy is 0.19.1

Comment: The `stats` module must be explicity imported before using it.  Replace `import scipy` with `import scipy.stats`.  Then you can write `scipy.stats.describe(a, axis=0, ddof=1, bias=True, nan_policy='propagate')`.  I'd make that an answer, but this question is a duplicate (it is a SciPy FAQ).

Comment: Oh thanks, I got it. So is it correct to say the stats is a subpackage of scipy?

Comment: That's what I've always called it, and so has SciPy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/general.html#scipy-organization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'module' object (scipy) has no attribute 'misc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581593/attributeerror-module-object-scipy-has-no-attribute-misc)