# how u can fix this problem AttributeError: 'scipy' object (scipy) has no attribute 'misc'?

Tags: python, scipy

I updated from ubuntu 12.04 to ubuntu 12.10 and the python module I have written suddenly no longer works with the error message that the module scipy does not have the attribute 'misc'. This worked previously. I am still using python 2.7 after the update. Here is where the code crashes

Comment: `scipy.misc` still exists. `scipy.misc.imsave` has been removed, but that would produce a different error message. You've done something wrong on top of trying to use `scipy.misc.imsave`.

Comment: Also, you should really update to Python 3. Almost everything is dropping Python 2 support, including the imageio module you switched to.

Answer (score -1):

it's very  easy
u have to do  this step
**1**-pip install imageio

**2**-import imageio

**3**-replace  scipy.misc.imsave(image_name,data)

with this code

imageio.imwrite(image_name, data)

enjoy............