# Selenium module calling error

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I'm trying to write a script to log into a website and press a button, without opening a browser or some such.  I keep getting an error when I try to setup my selenium remote case, I keep getting a TYPEERROR: 'module' object is not callable.

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class ClockInRemote(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://signin/ess.aew/DEFAULT")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_clock_in_remote(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/attendance/ess.aew/DEFAULT")
        sel.type("id=AE_BadgeID_ID", "1234")
        sel.type("id=AE_PIN_ID", "5678")
        sel.click("css=input[type=\"submit\"]")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")
        self.failUnless(sel.is_text_present("Punch IN or OUT"))
        sel.click("id=ID_AE_PageActivity301q1")
        sel.wait_for_page_to_load("30000")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This gives me the error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_clock_in_remote (__main__.ClockInRemote)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyScripts\ClockInRemote.py", line 8, in setUp
    self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://signin/ess.aew/DEFAULT")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.011s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Oh, Windows 10, with Python 2.7.13  and I installed Selenium today.

Comment: You're attempting to pass arguments to a module, not a class or function object.
There's probably an underlying class you intend to be calling rather than selenium itself.

Comment: Please link to the docs that make you think this will work: `selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://signin/ess.aew/DEFAULT")`

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Drew is using [Selenium 1 (Selenium RC)](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp#selenese-as-programming-code).

Comment: @Kanak. OIC, I wasn't even aware of that being a thing :)

Comment: @DrewCourtney. What is the output of `print(selenium.__version__)`?

Comment: Mad Physicist the output shows 3.4.3 as the Selenium Version.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class ClockInRemote(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium(...) #<----------------
        #[...]
```

know that the object on the [RHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation) whose name is `selenium` is not a [callable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callable_object), i.e. it is not a function. Actually, it is a [module](https://www.google.com/search?q=module+python). You cannot *call* a *module*. You cannot do `selenium(...)`

I guess that what you actually want is using the function defined in the module, and both have the same nam. SImply replace `selenium(...)` by `selenium.selenium(...)`, I mean

```
class ClockInRemote(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium.selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://signin/ess.aew/DEFAULT")
        #[...]
```

---

If you get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'selenium'
```

you *may* want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781522/why-do-python-modules-sometimes-not-import-their-sub-modules). Try this out

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import selenium         #<----------------
import unittest, time, re

class ClockInRemote(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium(...) #<----------------
        #[...]
```

---

#### Update

You are using Selenium's version 3.+

As it reads [here](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2016/10/13/selenium-3-0-out-now/)

> The major change in Selenium 3.0 is we’re removing the original Selenium Core implementation and replacing it with one backed by WebDriver. This will affect all users of the Selenium RC APIs.

This is very likely the reason why your code is not working anymore. You have two solutions. Either you downgrade your version of selenium (which is rarely a good idea), or you must re-develop a new testing framework which works with this new version.

Comment: I think that is closer to the answer, when I try it I get:  `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'selenium'`

Comment: @DrewCourtney. Get the code back to its original state. I mean undo what I asked you to do. And change the first `import` related line from `import selenium` to `from selenium import selenium` . See update. Does it work ?

Comment: Thank you @Kanak, that was the original method I was trying to use but it gives me this:  `from selenium import selenium  ImportError: cannot import name selenium`

Comment: @DrewCourtney. Ok. Which version of selenium are you using ? Type `import selenium` and then type `selenium.__version__`. What does it print ?

Comment: I am using Selenium ver. 3.4.3

Comment: @DrewCourtney. Is it a problem for you to downgrade your version of selenium ? At least to get sure of what the problem really is ? If this is not a problem, you could open a command prompt and type, e.g. `pip install selenium==2.53.0`.

Comment: What did you do finally @Drew ?

Comment: Sadly, @Kanak I had to move on to a different project, and this got laid on someone else's feet.  They already had Selnium downgraded on their computer I think and they were able to do what I was trying to do.