# Proper way to import from scipy submodules

Tags: python, scipy

I am having trouble understanding why the following ways to access `scipy.sparse.linalg.norm` work and do not work respectively:

```
(base) ➜  ~ ipython
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.13.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from scipy import sparse                                                                                                               

In [2]: sparse.linalg.norm                                                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-bfa688e1c7b4> in <module>
----> 1 sparse.linalg.norm

AttributeError: module 'scipy.sparse' has no attribute 'linalg'

In [3]: from scipy.sparse.linalg import norm                                                                                                   

In [4]: import scipy; scipy.__version__                                                                                                        
Out[4]: '1.4.1'
```

Can someone explain?

Additionally, I think I remember using sparse.linalg.norm directly in the past, where it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781522/why-do-python-modules-sometimes-not-import-their-sub-modules) brilliant answer:

> In Python, modules need to be imported before they're accessible.
>   import logging imports just the logging module. It so happens that
>   logging is a package with submodules, but those submodules are still
>   not automatically loaded. So, you need to explicitly import
>   logging.handlers before you can access it.
>
> If you're wondering why it looks like sometimes you don't need those
>   extra imports: some packages import some or all of their submodules
>   when they are imported -- simply by doing those imports in their
>   **init**.py files. In other cases it might be that something else that you import, also imported logging.handlers. It doesn't matter which
>   piece of code does the import; as long as something in your process
>   imports logging.handlers before you access it, it'll be there. And
>   sometimes a module that looks like a package really isn't one, like os
>   and os.path. os isn't a package, it just imports the correct other
>   module (for your platform) and calls it path, just so you can access
>   it as os.path.

So if we delve into `scipy.sparse` and see its `__init__.py` we see that they have not imported the submodules while loading the base module. This is the block of code which does the imports:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

# Original code by Travis Oliphant.
# Modified and extended by Ed Schofield, Robert Cimrman,
# Nathan Bell, and Jake Vanderplas.

import warnings as _warnings

from .base import *
from .csr import *
from .csc import *
from .lil import *
from .dok import *
from .coo import *
from .dia import *
from .bsr import *
from .construct import *
from .extract import *
from ._matrix_io import *

# For backward compatibility with v0.19.
from . import csgraph
```

---

So for your question, all you have to do is:

```
from scipy.sparse import linalg
```

And then call `linalg.norm` on a sparse matrix.

Comment: Thanks, one more: why does it become possible to call `sparse.linalg.norm` after having used `from scipy.sparse import linalg` ?

Comment: @P.Camilleri Because it's a method inside a module. The module knows the methods it contains, it's similar to why you can use `sparse.rand` when you import sparse from scipy.

Comment: Well not exactly since `from scipy import sparse` is not used in what I meanr. So I'd expect `linalg.norm` to work, but not necessarily `sparse.linalg.norm`