# Scipy strange import behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Scipy has an different way of handling submodules to Numpy, for example

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
A = np.eye(4)
np.linalg.det(A)
sp.linalg.det(A)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'linalg'
```

This is moderately annoying because of the asymmetry with respect to Numpy, but it is exactly the behaviour that the documentation describes.  The proper usage according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.det.html?highlight=linalg%20det) is

```
from scipy import linalg
import numpy as np
A = np.eye(4)
np.linalg.det(A)
linalg.det(A)  # using Scipy
```

which works just fine.

Now, here's the weird thing

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm  # extra line inserted into first example
A = np.eye(4)
np.linalg.det(A)
sp.linalg.det(A)
```

then the Numpy-style code works just fine.  The extra line causes `linalg` to be added to the namespace `sp`, a side effect of the extra import.

I get the programming pattern I want but the third line is not easy to explain in example code.

QUESTION: why does Scipy do this?  is there any more straightforward way to have it so that Scipy behaves more Numpyish?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do Python modules sometimes not import their sub-modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781522/why-do-python-modules-sometimes-not-import-their-sub-modules)

Comment: For the reasons mentioned in the linked question, I would recommend you to do something straightforward like first doing your `import scipy as sp` and then just simply doing: `import scipy.linalg`. This will allow you to use `sp.linalg.det` and other stuff. No need to import something unnecessary like `expm`.

Comment: Thanks @Mercury I'll take that!  Still there is something different about the package/module structure of Scipy vs Numpy that makes it necessary to do this.  I still wonder what's behind that design decision, especially given the close links between the two projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you almost never need or to want `import scipy as sp` or anything like that.

There is almost nothing in the top level scipy namespace. All useful stuff is in subpackages (one exception is LowLevelCallable which *is* in the top-level namespace). This way, users are better off either importing from subpackages, `from scipy.signal import detrend`, or importing subpackages themselves (`from scipy import signal; signal.detrend(...)`).

As to the disparity with numpy, numpy is very much the opposite: *a lot* of useful stuff is in the top-level namespace, so you import it from there.
Unless you're using `np.linalg`, `np.random`, `np.fft` or `np.testing`, which are public-facing usable submodules.